# What does the symbol `!` mean in type declarations in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, programming-languages, type-systems

In my studies of Haskell, I see the symbol `!` used in type declarations. See an example:

```hs
data Foo = MkFoo
  { _bar :: !Bar
    , ...
  }
```

My question is: why is it used and what is the difference to a declaration without it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fields marked with an exclamation point are made strict at the site of applications of the associated constructor. For example, your data declaration would be exactly the same as without the `!` but writing the following kind of thing everywhere your code uses `MkFoo`:

```
bar `seq` MkFoo { _bar = bar }
```

Full details are [in the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-710004.2.1).

Comment: It's worth noting that the main reason for making fields strict is typically that [this allows the compiler to _unbox_ the stored values](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#ghc-flag--funbox-small-strict-fields), i.e. instead of storing a pointer to a thunk/value (which would in case of e.g. `Int` consume as much space as the value itself!), you store the integer right there in place.

Comment: Semantically, yes. Operationally, no. The compiler knows that a strict field is already evaluated. Suppose you write `data Grump = Grump !Bar !Char` and `goom :: Foo -> (Grump, Int); goom (Foo b) = (Grump b 't', 7)`. When the result pair is forced, this will build the result pair entirely out of constructors and primitives. If, however, `Foo`'s field were lazy, then forcing the result pair would place a *thunk* in the first component that, when forced, would force the `Bar` and build the `Grump`. Strict fields can be really helpful for cutting down constant factors.